# AJAX and PHP Can I Set a variable onclick? no Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, post

I'm not understanding AJAX, but I've heard it's used for this type of thing. Or if you have another solution, that's fine too.  I've seen similar questions, with bits of code but no complete examples that I can understand. I have a webpage with no php variable set.  I want to click a button, and without reloading the page, set a php variable and run the full code again and see that variable displayed. I'd love to see a working example without jquery.  I assume I'd need 2 webpages.  Call them page1.php and page2.php
Something like this...

```
<!Doctype>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

// some kind of ajax formula here...

</script>
</head>

<body>

<button onclick='callAjax()'>link</button>

<?php 
if (isset($test)) echo $test;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

and page2.php would simply be used to set the variable like...

```
<?php
$test=123;
?>
```

Comment: What you want is indeed possible with Ajax. Just not the way you display it right here. PHP is _always_ executed before output. So you can't perform some PHP code (in the same php file) after clicking a button. Instead you save the response ajax got into a javascript variable and pass that on to your website (html).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to post to a php script that returns a variable. This can be accomplished by using xhr but jQuery makes it easier using $.ajax.

There is a good intro to this here ... https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

PHP is server side and Javascript is client side. Your Javascript will 'post' to the php file and the php file will return a response which the page can use without reloading. You can check if the php is responding by using the developer tools of your browser and looking at the network tab in chrome for instance. The shortcut to Dev tools is F12.